# Post data using XMLHttpRequest to laravel 5.2 controller as request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel-5

I have done posting/updating successfully with javascript XMLHttpRequest() to php $_REQUEST like:

```
 function ajax_edit(e_id){

          var edit_form = document.getElementById('edit_form'+e_id);

            var e_name = document.getElementById('name'+e_id).value,
                        e_email = document.getElementById('email'+e_id).value,
                        e_contact = document.getElementById('contact'+e_id).value,
                        e_status = document.getElementById('status'+e_id).value;
                    xmlhttp.open('GET', 'hello-world.php?edit=yes&id='+e_id+'&name='+e_name+'&email='+e_email+'&contact='+e_contact+'&status='+e_status, true);
                    xmlhttp.send();


            $('#edit'+e_id).modal('hide');
                return false;   
                edit_form.reset();
        }
```

And my php work was like:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['edit'])){
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, strip_tags($_REQUEST['name']));
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, strip_tags($_REQUEST['email']));
    $contact = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, strip_tags($_REQUEST['contact']));
    $status = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, strip_tags($_REQUEST['status']));
    $edit_sql = "UPDATE users SET name = '$name', email = '$email', contact = '$contact', status = '$status' WHERE id = '$_REQUEST[id]'";
    $run_edit = mysqli_query($conn, $edit_sql);
}
```

Now I am trying to apply the same process to another Laravel 5.2 project but don't know how to do, specially the url **(hello-world.php?edit=yes)** part from where I will send data to my controller as request.

So far I have done with this:

```
            function submit_form(edit_id){

            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

            var edit_form = document.getElementById('edit_form'+edit_id);
            var url = "{{ URL::to('updatelabdetails'); }}";

            var edit_labname = document.getElementById('labname'+edit_id).value,
                edit_pcname = document.getElementById('pcname'+edit_id).value;

                alert(edit_pcname);

            var params = "labname='+edit_labname+'&pcname='+edit_pcname";


                alert(params);

                xmlhttp.open('GET', url+"?"+params, true);
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

                if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);

                        }
                    }
                xmlhttp.send();


                return false;

        }
```

But only able to output till **alert(edit_pcname);** part.

My Route:

```
   Route::post('updatelabdetails', 'LoginController@updateLabDetails');
```

My Controller:

```
    public function updateLabDetails(Request $request){
        $post = $request->all();
        var_dump($post);
        die();
        }
```

After submitting its going to some url like **/showlabdetails?** with MethodNotAllowedHttpException error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are sending a GET request `xmlhttp.open('GET', url+"?"+params, true);` while the route is defined as POST `Route::post('updatelab...` and thats why you get *MethodNotAllowedHttpException*.

Comment: I checked them ('GET, 'POST') by changing but same problem. please suggest me with the url part with "?" because I'm not getting the actual value in alert(params); as the "var params" is not getting the right value.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your submit_form function like this

```
function submit_form(edit_id){
    var edit_labname = document.getElementById('labname'+edit_id).value,
            edit_pcname = document.getElementById('pcname'+edit_id).value;

    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "updatelabdetails";
    var params = "labname='+edit_labname+'&pcname='+edit_pcname";
    http.open("POST", url, true);

    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
    }
   }
   http.send(params);
}
```

Comment: its not happening either :(
please let me know how this [xmlhttp.open('GET', 'hello-world.php?edit=yes&id='+e_id+'&name='+e_name+'&email='+e_email+'&contact='+e_contact+'&status='+e_status, true);] type of code have to write in blade template for laravel 5.2 controller as request.

Comment: `xmlhttp.open('GET', 'hello-world.php?edit=yes&id='+e_id+'&name='+e_name+'&email=‌​'+e_email+'&contact=‌​'+e_contact+'&status‌​='+e_status, true);` 
it's a *GET* request that's why we can send *Query String* with key value pair.

Comment: ok I am putting both get/post same for js & route, now please tell me how to convert this xmlhttp.open() code for laravel controller. what will be the replacement of [hello-world.php?edit=yes]

Answer (score 0):

Your laravel roure isn't correct you've registered `POST` route and accessing the `GET` one.

Change `Route::post('updatelabdetails', 'LoginController@updateLabDetails');` to `Route::get('updatelabdetails', 'LoginController@updateLabDetails');`

Comment: what will be the replacement of [hello-world.php?edit=yes] for laravel 5.2 controller???

Comment: In JavaScript

```js
xmlhttp.open('GET', 'hello-world?edit=yes&id='+e_id+'&name='+e_name+'&email='+e_email+'&contact='+e_contact+'&status='+e_status, true);
```

In Route
```php
Route::get('hello-world', 'YourController@methodName');
```

Answer (score 0):

> you need to add token in your request as said in the laravel documentation. see this link https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf